# Finding Table Class Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble finding a table while web scraping using python/Beautiful Soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.espn.com/nba/player/gamelog/_/id/3907387/ben-simmons'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

t = soup.find_all('table' , class_='Table Table--align-right')
```

This is returning null

Comment: You should include a **minimal** example of the markup - enough to reproduce the problem.  Please read [mcve].

Comment: I used exactly the same code you did and got results.

Comment: How do you know it is returning null?

Comment: That table is definitely there, maybe it didn't like your request with zero headers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas read_html to read the table as a list and find the required list from that as below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.espn.com/nba/player/gamelog/_/id/3907387/ben-simmon'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[3]
print(df)
```